# Conditionally switching destination directory in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp task as shown below:

```
gulp.task('beautify', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsFileSrc)
        .pipe(prettify({
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
});
```

My directory structure is like:

```
|_assets/
  |_less/ */less files here */
|_src/
  |_scripts/ */js files here */
```

Currently it beautifies the `.js` files and puts them in the same location.

I want this same task to beautify my `.less` files as well like

```
gulp.task('beautify', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsFileSrc, lessFileSrc)
        .pipe(prettify({
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/')); // <-- .less files should go in /assets
});
```

But the problem is that, the `.less` fles reside in an `assets` folder outside `src` folder.

How do I tell gulp to put the js files relative to `src` folder and less files relative to `assets` folder..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) to apply a `.pipe()` to only certain files:

```
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');

gulp.task('beautify', function() {
  return gulp.src([jsFileSrc, lessFileSrc])
    .pipe(prettify({
        debug: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', gulp.dest('src/')))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.less', gulp.dest('assets/')))
});
```